# Seeking faster access/transfer times for accounting application

Tags: performance, hard-drive

Our accounting software, Sage 50, has been getting slower to open on workstations and reading the company file. The company file only contains 2 years worth of transactions, and we just cleared out 2011 so the file size has gotten a lot smaller. There are 10 users, 6 of which are on it all day, 4 are on and off throughout the day.

Our network is entirely GbE and the switches are set to prioritize traffic on that port number. Watching network traffic, we barely use 40% of the network capability on the workstation, so I don't think that is our bottleneck.

Our server contains two older Raptors Sata 2(3GB/s) 150GB in RAID 1. We were considering switching to SSD's, but a lot of what I read says to stay away from MLC's, especially for production environment and definitely avoid putting them in a RAID config.

So would upgrading to newer Raptors with SATA 3(6GB/s) offer noticable benefits? What other options are out there that aren't so expensive? Trying to keep it to 200-300 per drive. We need at least 150GB, but going to 250-300GB would be better as it gives us more room to grow. We have about 30% space remaining on what we have now.

Comment: Instead of guessing, why don't you fire up perfmon and find out *exactly* where your bottleneck is?

Comment: There are way too many [things that could cause your performance problems](http://www.steveblencowe.com/sageslow.htm), and your question doesn't reflect that you've checked any of them. Please go through the list and edit your question to reflect what you have tried to resolve the problem.

Comment: Tha above advice are things you probably need to do first.  AFA using SSDs, just make sure your drive controller supports using SSDs.  SSDs generally will help, but unless you know where your bottleneck is, you are just guessing.  I've noticed that swapping out the workstation HDs with SSDs seem to make the users much happier than doign so on the server.    But start with doing perfmon on the server and see if your bottleneck is even there...  Also, keep in mind that not all controllers support SATA 6Gb....so make sure your controller supports it or you are wasting your money...

Comment: The bottleneck is the IO on the server.

Comment: Can you post some graphs of the IO that you took to help come to this conclusion? It will help determine the answer to the question.

Comment: How do I post images on here?

Answer (score 1):

I can start with your first sentence "Our accounting software, Sage 50, has been getting slower to open on workstations and reading the company file"

1.) Opening the Sage 50 application on your workstation has nothing to do with the server, its a large application and tends to eat up a decent amount of memory when used so you might consider the SSD for the workstation if you have a Sata III controller (which means the machine is atleast newer and isn't starved for RAM).  That will allow faster opening of the application.

2.) Sage 50 uses the Pervasive database which may or may not be tuned for 10 simultaneous users accessing data, so you might have a bottleneck there, you'll find out once you do a performance check.

3.) Raptors in a RAID 1 may not be as fast as you think if you have an onboard software RAID controller.  You might be better off picking up a $400 used Dell Poweredge server (on eBAY) with (6) SAS 146gb drives with Hardware RAID and setting up a RAID 10, will give you an immense IO boost and some redundancy.